# How to Wait for Java file to be writen then make instance from it using classloader?

Tags: java, file

I write some code which create java file then make instance from it using `ClassLoader` my problem is that `ClassLoader` throw `ClassNotFoundException` if I don't put sleep after writing the file.

So, I need a way that makes the thread sleeps until the file finish writing all the file.

Something like:

```
File javaFile = new File(serverPath + pkgname + "/" + className + ".java")

if (javaFile.getParentFile().exists() || javaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            Writer writer = null;
            writer = new FileWriter(javaFile);
            writer.write(sb.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Method method = Class.forName(pkgname + "." + className).getMethod("main", String[].class);
            String[] params = new String[0]; // init params accordingly
            method.invoke(null, (Object) params);
  }
```

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay, check the question again,

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the compiler? Or don't you call it and assume some IDE (Eclipse?) is running in background compiling your Java files? In the latter case you will see a surprise once you package/deploy your application...

Comment: If you wants to execute a `.java` file you may use [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/). Java source code must be compiled into a `.class` file (byte code) before loading into the JVM.

Comment: If possible, consider using a proxy http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: my problem is not compiling the java code, my problem is that the thread continue the work and go to class forname before FilleWriter finish writing how to make it sleeps?

Comment: @mihi it`s just a part of my code not all my code

Comment: And where is your file ever compiled?

Comment: @AmgadMHM I can assure you that once you call `writer.close`, it will block until the **java** file has been written to disk. Your problem is that you have some other code elsewhere that seems to scan for that Java file and compile it to the **class** file, which you try to load with `Class.forName`. You have to adjust it so that you can wait for it (for example using `wait`/`notify` pattern) until it has compiled everything. But the probably better way would be to call that code directly between your `writer.close` and the `Class.forName`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the compiler doesn`t  generate the .class files in the build path so the program waits for the IDE's Auto Compile to be performed.